# How should I prepare an already painted plasterboard ceiling?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, preparation

We are repainting the interior of our whole house. We start with the ceiling of each room and the newer ceilings where gyprock has been used we don't have a problem. The older ceilings that are made from plasterboard are a nightmare! We scrape off the peeling paint and refill with filler and then wait for it to dry and sand. When we start to paint in the areas that we haven't touched (they looked fine - nothing peeling etc) the paint bubbles and starts to peel on the roller. Does anyone know what we should do to the ceiling to stop this happening?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you post a picture of the problematic areas? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: When ws the house painted last for the areas you are describing? When was it built? Is it lead based paint you are peeling? Oil based? How old is the paint you are using? is it oil based, is it acrylic? Did you stir it?

Comment: ... oh, and what is the filler you are using? Are you hand sanding it down after application and does it require a primer? Are you allowing it enough time to dry per the instructions on the product? And lastly, what is your climate like currently?